# Mixing cordova web and native iOS code

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have inherited a Cordova project that mixes web code with native code.

I'm using cordova CLI 6.3.1 and the cordova ios platform version is 3.9.2.

Whilst working I come across this warning in the console.

> Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-ios is
>   being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-ios@4.0.0 or newer.

However, when I try updating the ios platform version using `cordova platform update ios --save` it completely wipes out all files in the "platforms" folder - which currently includes all the custom iOS project files, i.e. custom classes and what not.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with our project setup? 
What is the recommended way to mix and match cordova web and native iOS code so that updating the cordova ios platform doesn't nuke everything?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the files under `/platforms` are generated on the fly based on changes that are made in `/www`. Running `cordova prepare ios`, `cordova build ios`, `cordova platform update ios`, or `cordova run ios`, will always nuke the `platforms/ios` folder and retreat it based on `/www`.

You mentioned your project has custom native code. Is that native code built as a cordova plugin? If so then you should be good following the standard workflow. Work in `/www`. Test your project `cordova run ios`.

If not, you might want to consider refactoring the native code you have as a plugin.

Look at this [plugin's](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) code structure as an example.
Follow this [guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) on how to start developing a plugin.

Comment: Exactly the native code is not all plugins. So generally you would expect all native code to be a plugin??

Comment: My opinion is that yes, it should. This way if down the road you want to support an additional platform you just add the functionality to your plugin and the web codebase remains the same. The plugin acts as your interface and should be the only thing that changes.

Comment: An additional platform might be Android in my case, right? In that case you would need to write a completely new  plugin, wouldn't you? I was kind of hoping there would be some convention for copying non plugin native code from some location outside of the platforms folder after running the types of commands you mention. Unfortunately not, apparently.

Comment: Yes. iOS, Android, Windows Phone. These are all platforms that Cordova supports. You wouldn't need to rewrite your plugin. You would just need to add another entry in your plugin definition to include the new platform you're supporting. See my updated answer for some links.